# Unable to include shoulda tests in a module

Tags: ruby, minitest, shoulda, ruby-2.1

I am using Rails with MiniTest and have several classes that are all related through inheritance.  I would like to reuse tests by placing them in a module.  Something like this:

```
module MyModule
  should 'work' do
    assert true
  end
end
```

Then in my tests:

```
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  require MyModule
end
```

The problem is that I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method should`

What am I missing?

Comment: If you move the `should 'work' do...` method definition into the `MyTest` body, do you still get the error? Try replacing `should` with `it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) That's not what `require` is for.**

**2a) You probably want to `extend` a module and define a method that you can call instead.**

```
module MyModule
  def should_work
    should 'work' do
      assert true
    end
  end
end

class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  extend MyModule
  should_work
end
```

**2b) Alternatively, you can just `extend` the module and have the tests automatically called via `Module.extended`:**

```
module MyModule
  def self.extended(base)
    base.should_work
  end

  def should_work
    should 'work' do
      assert true
    end
  end
end

class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  extend MyModule
end
```

**2c) You can put everything in `Module.extended` too:**

```
module MyModule
  def self.extended(base)
    base.should 'work' do
      assert true
    end
  end
end

class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  extend MyModule
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to require your module file in MyTest class, on the top:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../spec/modules/module_file_name'
```

Or you can put this relative_path into spec_helper and than just require 'spec_helper' .

Hope this help you

Comment: yeah, the file has been successfully imported. otherwise, he wouldn't be getting a NoMethodError.

Comment: @acsmith is correct the file is getting imported correctly.